# Search directory and delete all files that have hard links?

Tags: c#, .net, kernel32

I've been working on a project where the software needs to remove only the files which have links somewhere else (hard links) in a directory of 40,000+ files. I've been using the following with some success:

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION
        {
            public uint FileAttributes;
            public FILETIME CreationTime;
            public FILETIME LastAccessTime;
            public FILETIME LastWriteTime;
            public uint VolumeSerialNumber;
            public uint FileSizeHigh;
            public uint FileSizeLow;
            public uint NumberOfLinks;
            public uint FileIndexHigh;
            public uint FileIndexLow;
        }       

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandle(SafeFileHandle handle, out BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
           string lpFileName,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare dwShareMode,
           IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
           IntPtr hTemplateFile);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(SafeHandle hObject);

        public static int GetFileLinkCount(string filepath)
        {
            try
            {
                int result = 0;
                SafeFileHandle handle = CreateFile(filepath, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, FileAttributes.Archive, IntPtr.Zero);
                BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION fileInfo = new BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION();
                if (GetFileInformationByHandle(handle, out fileInfo))
                    result = (int)fileInfo.NumberOfLinks;
                CloseHandle(handle);
                return result;
            }
            catch { return 1; }
        }
```

When I call `GetFileLinkCount`, I get what I want (a value > 1 confirms the file is a hard link.). However, when I loop through all of the folders in a directory and keep calling `GetFileLinkCount`, the program enters break mode and throws a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'External component has thrown an exception.'`, which doesn't help me debug much. This is how I am calling it:

```
string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\P3D", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

for(int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
{
    if (GetFileLinkCount(paths[i]) > 1)
    {
        File.Delete(paths[i]);
    }
}
```

After a number of seconds, the application crashes with the above mentioned exception. It's odd because some of the hard links are being deleted, but some are not since the application crashes before it can finish the loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest adding some error handling: 1. check the return from the API calls for failure; 2. Use `GetLastError` to get the specific error code.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the suggestion, I am getting error code 18 which is `There are no more files.` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Which API is failing with `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES`? (I would only expect that from one of the folder enumeration APIs which you are not using.)

Comment: @Richard The error code comes from the CreateFile API. (I change SetLastError to false for the others just to be sure)

Comment: The odd part is that the API only fails sometimes...

Comment: I suspect you are seeing a value left from the underlying APIs used by `GetFiles`: you need to check the return value *and only if that indicates failure* check the error code. Please update the quesiton with your current code (I'm having to guess how you have changed your code).